# Why is the movie title "Wrong Turn"?

Tags: title, wrong-turn

I watched this movie, **Wrong Turn**. Some 3 deformity face guys attacking young boys & girls who stuck up at their town.

How does **Wrong Turn** title suit to this horror subject?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pretty clear from the IMDB synopsis for the movie.

> Chris Flynn is driving his car for a job interview in another city. However, an accident with a trunk transporting chemical products blocks the highway and Chris looks for an **alternative route** through the mountains of West Virginia to accomplish his schedule
>
> <sup>[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0295700/plotsummary)</sup>

Taking the alternate route had such disastrous consequences that it can only be considered a "Wrong Turn".